# NullPointerException Android

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, logcat

While running the application I'm getting these errors

> 10-09 10:20:57.138: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rika/com.rika.LatihanActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 10-09 10:20:57.138: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Its the activity class

```
public class LatihanActivity extends Activity{
    private RadioButton radioButton;
    private TextView quizQuestion;  
    
    private int rowIndex = 1;
    private int questNo=0;
    private boolean checked=false;
    private boolean flag=true;
    
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    
    String[] corrAns = new String[5];
    
    final DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    
    Cursor c1;
    Cursor c2;
    Cursor c3;

    int counter=1;
    String label;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String options[] = new String[19];
  
        final RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdbGp1);
    
         // layout params to use when adding each radio button
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                    RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    
        try {
            db.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        quizQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                
        displayQuestion();
                     
        /*Displays the next options and sets listener on next button*/
        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(btnNext_Listener);

        /*Saves the selected values in the database on the save button*/
        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(btnSave_Listener);   

        c3 = db.getCorrAns();

        for (int i=0;i<=4;i++) {
            corrAns[i]=c3.getString(0);
            c3.moveToNext();
        }

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdbGp1);
         
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i=0; i<radiogroup.getChildCount() ; i++) {
                    RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i);                     
                    String text;
                              
                    if (btn.isPressed() && btn.isChecked() && questNo < 5) {
                        Log.e("corrAns[questNo]",corrAns[questNo]);
                        if (corrAns[questNo].equals(btn.getText()) && flag==true) {
                            flag=false;
                            checked = true; 
                        } else if(checked==true) {
                            flag=true;
                            checked = false;
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
        });        
    }
          
    /*Called when next button is clicked*/
    private View.OnClickListener btnNext_Listener= new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flag=true;
            checked = false;
            questNo++;
        
            if (questNo < 5) {
                c1.moveToNext();
                displayQuestion();
            }
        }

    };
    
    private View.OnClickListener btnSave_Listener= new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {}
    };


    private void displayQuestion()  {
        //Fetching data quiz data and incrementing on each click
        
        c1=db.getQuiz_Content(rowIndex);
        
        c2 =db.getAns(rowIndex++);
            
        quizQuestion.setText(c1.getString(0));
            
        radioGroup.removeAllViews();
        for (int i=0;i<=3;i++) {
            //Generating and adding 4 radio buttons dynamically 
            radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
            radioButton.setText(c2.getString(0));
            radioButton.setId(i);
            c2.moveToNext();
            radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
        }
        
    }
}
```

All these issues happened when run the application

> 10-09 11:13:15.128: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(68): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rika/com.rika.LatihanActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at com.rika.LatihanActivity.displayQuestion(LatihanActivity.java:198)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at com.rika.LatihanActivity.onCreate(LatihanActivity.java:69)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>
> 10-09 11:13:56.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     ... 11 more

Comment: In which line does the NullPointerException occur?

Comment: @yaswanth : yup i declared it already

Comment: @alextsc : how to check it? im sorry im very new in android

Comment: Post the entire Logcat log. It should be there.

Comment: Yeah as Michell said, it's easiest to post the whole exception stacktrace. It's in there, basically you go down the trace until a file/class of your own is mentioned. The line is in the brackets of that. We'll show you the line as an example when you post the trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possibility 1 :** you should declare your Acttivity on your Manifest File  ,

if you already did it and it still doesn't work , you should declare it with the name of the package if you activity is in another package :

```
<application ...>
<activity android:name="YouPackageName.YourActivity" /> // it should be on the <application> tag
</application>
```

and at last , Clean and RE execute your project .

**Possibility 2 :**

make sure that your RadioButtonGroup is defined on your main.xml layout , if it is , soo make sure that you didn't import the `android.R` ; you should use import `YourPackage.R;`

and at last Clean and rebuild your project .

**NB : you didn't give the full stack trace of your NullPointerException , so we can't determine what is the exact problem in your code ,**

Comment: i already tried your suggestion but still get errors. i added the complete error statements. thank you

Comment: line 69 : displayQuestion(); </br>                                line 198: radioGroup.removeAllViews();

Comment: the line 198 generate a NullPointerException  , soo your radioGroup is null, please add the code of all your activity to figure out the cause of the problem :)

Comment: the radioGroup is null , make sure that you have tried my solution : *Possibility 2 *. and also remove `final` from the declaration of your radioGroup

Comment: for radio button, i added dynamically, so i just coded radioGroup in xml file. I did your possibility2 suggestion and now i get other errors "Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0" . Is it means no row in my database?

Comment: thx.. i solved it... i was recognized the name of database attribute wrongly :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating database but u should open it after creating the database.

```
public void opendatabase() throws SQLException
{
    //Open the database
    String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}
```

Well i m just guessing. if you will show your database class then it will be more helpful.
Or you can visit http://androidlearningbegin.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-application-to-connect-to-your.html if you are using externally created sqlite database.